# "why is current the derivative of charge and not integral of charge?"

Tags: electric-current, charge

Current is defined as the **amount of** charge passing a given point per unit time. The word amount throws me off. sorry if this question seems dumb, but

why can current not be equal to integral of charge from time t=t1 to t2?

[image]

since we want to know the **amount** of charge passing a given point, we can add up charge from time t1 until time t2

Comment: Compare this to kinematics: "$\Delta x$ is defined as the **amount of** change in position. So $\Delta x = \int x \, dt$, since we want to know the **amount** of change in position, we add up the position."

Comment: You defined current as for 'per unit time' . Hope you have got enough hint..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Current is defined as the amount of charge passing a given point per
>   unit time.

In fact, electric current is *defined* as the *flow* of electric charge.  From the Wikipedia article [Electric current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current)

> An electric current is a flow of electric charge.

From the Britannica article [Electric current](https://www.britannica.com/science/electric-current)

> Electric current is a measure of the flow of charge

A *flow* is a rate, i.e., an amount over an elapsed time.  If an amount of electric charge $\Delta Q$ flows into a region in some time $\Delta t$, then there is an electric current into the region (with an average value of)

$$\bar{I} = \frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}$$

In the electric circuit context, we have a circuit law ([Kirchhoff's Current Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law_(KCL))) that requires the current into a region equal the current out of the region and so we can think of the current *through* the region, e.g., the body of a resistor.

Answer (score 0):

This is because current is strictly defined as the rate at which charge passes through a given cross sectional area of a conductor. Here, we are required to measure "how many" charges cross the perpendicular cross section in a given time, therefore derivative is used here as a 'rate measurer'.